# Pins on Pinterest link to 404 - yet link is valid

Tags: links, 404, error

this is a really strange one.

I've set up a bunch of pins on Pinterest linking through to our services which all work fine. Then I decided to do the same on our blog articles (we use Wordpress), yet everytime I click the link (and I've done this on different computers) the link goes to a 404 page on our site. However the link is valid and if you right click the pin and open in new window it opens fine.

I have contacted Pinterest who are next to useless. I have also tried different browsers, different computers and different Pinterest accounts.

I can't see any weirdness in my htaccess files causing this so I'm a little stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the link to the Pinterest page?

Comment: Sure here's a link showing the problem. If you click directly on the link it goes to an error, if you right click and open in new window it works fine: http://pinterest.com/pin/105342078755648946/

Comment: I guess this is a javascript problem. When I disabled javascript while on Pinterest, I don't get an error. There should be a kind of redirect handle from Pinterest when you click on an external link. But I can't find it ..

Comment: If it was your website, what would you do?

Comment: I will enabled url rewrite log and then check both url rewrite log & access log file to see the exact url that Pinterest try to redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I ran into the same issue. It turns out Pinterest first issues a HEAD request to the address to validate the link. My app (asp.net) was only allowing GET requests.